# `seq` and bash brace expansion failing

Tags: bash, brace-expansion, seq

IINM my system is failing when *`bash`ing*

```
for i in {0..10000000}; #   Seven zeroes.
do
    false;
done #   `bash` exited and its `tmux` pane/window was closed.
```

or

```
for i in $(seq 0 10000000); #   Seven zeroes.
do
    false;
done #   `bash` exited and its `tmux` pane/window was closed.
```

but not when

```
for i in {0..1000000}; #   Six zeroes.
do
    false;
done #   Finished correctly.
```

Can you please briefly explain the internals of this behavior and prompt a workaround for getting the task done?

Comment: For you my all loved XY friends, a big file with CRLFs only is what I am actually trying to get.

Comment: Testing `nl` with lines alot, tabs and XY pow are what I got.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`for i in {0..1000000}` and `for i in $(seq 1000000)` both build up a big list and then loop over it. That's inefficient and uses a lot of memory.

Use:

```
for ((i = 0; i<= 1000000; i++))
```

instead. Or POSIXly:

```
i=0; while [ "$i" -le 1000000 ]; do
  ...
  i=$(($i + 1))
done
```

Or:

```
seq 1000000 | xargs...
```

---

To get a file full of CRLFs:

```
yes $'\r' | head -n 1000000 >  file
```

Generally, loops should be avoided when possible in shells.

Comment: there's also the old `/dev/zero/` thing... like `tr \\0 \\r </dev/zero | tee - - - |` `dd` or `head` or whatever... It might be better to mount a tmpfs of that size and fill it then cp to a file. Maybe not...

Comment: @mikeserv, yes _Pourquoi faire simple quand on peut faire compliqué ?_ like they say in France.

Comment: dang man. you really are a funny guy sometimes. now I have to translate that... ahh. the double entendre. that's probably French too. and, yeah, I dunno why I do. but I do.

Comment: Telling you to work a _pearl_ for it.

Answer (score 1):

@Stéphane Chazelas gave a great answer up there.

Mine is not an answer. I just it got curious about the efficiency of the different solutions, so I thought I should share my results...

```
~# i=0 ; time while [ "$i" -le 1000000 ]; do ((i++)) ;done
real    0m21.753s

~# time for ((i = 0; i<= 1000000; i++))  ;do : ;done
real    0m15.791s

~# time for i in {0..1000000} ;do : ;done
real    0m8.897s

~# time for i in $(seq 0 1000000) ;do : ;done
real    0m7.760s

:~# time seq 1000000 | xargs true
real    0m0.938s

~# time yes $'\r' | head -n 1000000 >/dev/null
real    0m0.048s
```

The `yes` answer is the clear winner. :-)
Besides, it actually does the work that the OP needed.